Simple proof that John's theorem is sharp?
We denote $B^n_p \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ the unit ball $\{\|x\|_p \leq 1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $p \in [1, \infty]$. Let $\mathcal{K}^n$ denote the class of symmetric convex bodies in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
One formulation of John's theorem is: if $K \in \mathcal{K}^n$ then there exists a linear map $L$ such that
$$
B^n_2 \subset L K \subset \sqrt{n} B^n_2. 
$$
Question: It is often claimed that John's theorem is sharp, meaning that the factor $\sqrt{n}$ cannot be diminished. In other words, there exists a set $K_\star \in \mathcal{K}^n$ such that if there exists a scalar $c$ and $L$ linear such that
$$
B^n_2 \subset L K_\star \subset c B^n_2, 
$$
then $c \geq \sqrt{n}$.
I have read that this can be shown by taking $K_\star = B^n_p$ for $p \in \{1, \infty\}$, however I am struggling to verify this. I do know that the following inequalities are sharp,
$$
\|x\|_2 \leq \|x\|_1 \leq \sqrt{n} \|x\|_2, \quad \|x\|_\infty \leq \|x\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n} \|x\|_\infty. 
$$
However, I am clearly missing a simple argument.
Concretely, to show the sharpness for John's theorem, I would need to show that if $p \in \{1, \infty\}$ and $L$ linear satisfies
$$
\|x\|_p \leq \|Lx\|_2 \leq c \|x\|_p
$$
then $c \geq \sqrt{n}$.

[+1 to your solution. Here I rewrite the solution in my own words to fill in some details for my own understanding, and also write out a solution for the $p=1$ case.]
Let $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ denote the standard basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

$p=\infty$
Suppose $L$ is such that $B_2^n \subset L B_p^n$.
$$\max_{\epsilon \in \{\pm 1\}^n} \left\|L \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i e_i\right)\right\|_2^2
= \max_{\epsilon \in \{\pm 1\}^n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(
\|Le_i\|_2^2 + 2 \epsilon_i \sum_{j > i}\epsilon_j \langle Le_i, Le_j\rangle
\right)
\ge \sum_{i=1}^n \|Le_i\|_2^2,$$
where the last step is obtained by choosing $\epsilon_n=1$ and choosing $\epsilon_i = \text{sign}\left(\sum_{j > i} \epsilon_j \langle Le_i, Le_j\rangle\right)$ for $i=n-1, n-2, \ldots, 1$. Since $e_i \in B_p^n$, the condition $B^n_2 \subset L B^n_p$ implies $\|Le_i\|_2 \ge 1$, so we have found some $\epsilon$ such that $x := \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i e_i$ satisfies $x \in B^n_p$ and $\|L x\|_2 \ge \sqrt{n}$. This shows $B^n_2 \subset LB^n_p \subset c B^n_2$ cannot hold if $c < \sqrt{n}$.

$p = 1$
Suppose $L$ is such that $LB^n_p \subset c B^n_2$.
$$\min_{\epsilon \in \{\pm 1\}^n} \left\|L \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\epsilon_i e_i\right)\right\|_2^2
= \min_{\epsilon \in \{\pm 1\}^n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(
\|Le_i\|_2^2 + 2 \epsilon_i \sum_{j > i}\epsilon_j \langle Le_i, Le_j\rangle
\right)
\le \sum_{i=1}^n \|Le_i\|_2^2,$$
where the last step is obtained by choosing $\epsilon_n=1$ and choosing $\epsilon_i = - \text{sign}\left(\sum_{j > i} \epsilon_j \langle Le_i, Le_j\rangle\right)$ for $i=n-1, n-2, \ldots, 1$. Since $e_i \in B^n_p$, the condition $LB^n_p \subset c B^n_2$ implies $\|Le_i\|_2 \le c$, so we have found some $\epsilon$ such that $x := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i e_i$ satisfies $x \in B^n_p$ and $\|Lx\|_2 \le c/\sqrt{n}$. This shows $B^n_2 \subset LB^n_p \subset c B^n_2$ cannot hold if $c < \sqrt{n}$.

Thanks, I think one can also argue that $p = 1$ follows from $p = \infty$ by duality.

We use $\ell^n_p$ as a short hand for $(\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|_p)$.
Let $L \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be linear, and let $\ell_i = L e_i$ where $e_i$ are the canonical basis vectors.
Note that if $\epsilon = (\epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n) \in \{\pm 1\}^n$, then
$$
L\epsilon = \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i \ell_i.
$$
Moreover,
$$
\|L\colon \ell^n_\infty \to \ell^n_2\| \geq \sqrt{\max_{\epsilon \in \{\pm 1\}^n} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \|\ell_i\|_2^2+ 2\epsilon_i\sum_{j > i}\langle \ell_i, \ell_j\rangle \epsilon_j}{1}}
\geq \|L\|_F
$$
Now note John's theorem implies
$$
1 \leq \|\ell_i\|_2, \quad \|Lx\|_2/\|x\|_p \leq c.
$$
Hence,
$$
c \geq \|L \colon \ell^n_\infty \to \ell^n_2\| \geq \sqrt{n},
$$
as needed.
